# WaveMaker app on Cloud Foundry With Drop Down List Box

Tags: cloud-foundry

Application works fine on local box and server.   Rolls out fine to the cloud but the drop down list box populated by a service variable in WM does not work in the cloud.   Any suggestions for a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Used Wavemaker 6.5.0.M3 and uploaded to cloud foudry.

Answer (score 1):

have you taken a look at the application logs on Cloud Foundry to see if it reveals any problems connecting to a data source? Make sure there is a MySQL instance bound to the application. If you give me the application URL I can take a look on your behalf..